# 502 bad gateway django elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I got the django app deployed with elastic beanstalk on aws, I setup postgresql for it as well to work with one on aws. Unfortunately, following

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html
```

I am getting 502 bad gateway after

```
eb open
```

I'm not really getting any errors, my app runs on local. I'm using the debug server, I also managed to run it on waitress. I was reading the oceans of info online and the only thing I can think of - do I need to actually deploy to a production server locally or can I just use EC2 for that? I'm learning about AWS as I go, so sorry if I'm not understanding something here :)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you ssh to the EB instance and verify that your django works from inside using `curl`?

Comment: Before I dive into stack to see how I do that, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Usually `eb ssh` works.

Comment: After running eb ssh, using keypair file I created I can see the ec2-user@ip console

I can also see: Following services are not running: web. In the monitoring

Comment: @Luk did you had any luck with this issue.. seeing the same error deploying a basic django app. I do see the nginx process up and running, but it just doesn't seem to be connecting.

Comment: Nevermind mine was simply a syntax issue ... needed to ensure that ALLOWED_HOSTS has a value in single quotes inside the square bracket.

Comment: Any solutions? Still have 502 error.